# Default search functionality google maps android

Tags: android

I want to get the default search functionality available in google maps on my android project.For example if i search "doctors in india" Gmaps will show many points, how can i get this work without using Itemized Overlay or by using some json request.Can somebody please suggest me an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google Places API to get a JSON for your query.

If you are looking to avoid using any library or API (because you have to register to get the API key) you could just use a webview and put a maps.google url.
for example:

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=New+York&z=13&t=m&output=embed
```

or

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=near:doctors+in+india&z=13&t=m&output=embed
```

You will find that the parameters here are not documented ,[Here](http://picchiri.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/google-maps-parameter/) is a link i found useful for the parameters.

Comment: Firstly thanks!...Could you please share some code on how to retrieve values using JSON query and display it on google maps using google api's android

Comment: So if you are looking to use the com.google.android.maps library in your code [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview) is how you use it. just follow the steps. Also make sure you get the apikey for google api v2. v1 is going to deprecate soon.

Comment: I have already loaded the Maps using google API's android.Now my need is to integrate search functionality on it.

Comment: perfect. i used google places API to get search results as a JSON. [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) is a comprehensive explanation on how to use that in your code. You already have done majority of it. Skip to point number 6 and 7. Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried that its a bit lengthy process....I changed my code to load url of maps in webview and i have google maps auto complete textview options...now what i need is to get the string from textview and send it to query string on  the URL and load the URL in the webview every time the user clicks search....any good ideas?

Comment: if the textview is within the webview, then it is a part of the google maps and we cant control it . but if its your own textview, then you can fire another url with what the user has entered in the textview.

Comment: Yeah Exactly!....I have done it!.....Finally one thing, Is anything available to make the performance of Webview better

Comment: well i am afraid i cant say anything to that other than saying use 3G/WiFi. Also you can add some sort of code for showing the progres of the urlload time. Chek it out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)